# Creating a Mapping Function Through TDD: Too Much Time Spent Writing Tests?

Tags: c#, tdd, testdrivendesign

I'm a big TDD enthusiast, and always strive to write tests before writing production code to ensure correct behavior of the code that I'm writing. Occasionally, however, several question if it is prudent to write a large body of tests for certain kinds of methods. This seems to come up most often when writing a mapper class.

```
public class FooBarMapper
{
    public Foo MapToFoo(Bar bar)
    {
        return new Foo
        {
            Id = bar.Id,
            Name = bar.Name,
            FooYuk = bar.Beverage,
            /* ... */
        };
    }
}
```

Say for example that there are about a dozen properties to map to above. In a TDD environment, before writing any of the mappings, I'd probably write a test. Something like `MapToFooMapsBeverageToFooYuk()`. The test fails, leading me to write the code to make it pass. I repeat this for each property to map. The question is: Is this taking test-first development too far? I personally don't think so, as I'd rather have a full suite of tests telling me exactly what the code does, but I'd like to hear what the community thinks.

Comment: Related: Have you tried AutoMapper?  http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper -- in some cases you can use it to avoid writing the mapping code, plus it has run-time verification which is perfect for writing quick tests.

Comment: That looks really interesting. I'm checking it out as we speak. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even Uncle Bob Martin, a staunch defender of TDD and all things TDD, says that you don't have to write unit tests for every trivial property (a trivial property being defined as a property that just gets and sets a member variable).

If you ever write a property that has side-effects (which I doubt you will), *then* you can add a unit test to it.  As DuffyMo points out, if your properties are covered by functional testing, there should be no need for unit tests, since there is no *specification* of functionality you are defining with the unit test, other than the trivial get/set.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Sometimes I simply resign myself to only writing Regression Tests (i.e. test that a field is mapped only after it has been discovered that it was accidentally omitted).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) was born for.

Comment: Po-TAY-to, po-TAH-to.  The lines between the two need not be so stark.  FitNesse seems like a great way to externalize these things.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I'd write a single test that tests all the trivial properties at once. It's not quite the standard way to do things, but eventually, the tests for individual trivial properties would probably be refactored into a single test for all properties. Since the properties are trivial,  I propose starting off with the test you'd have ended with.

Answer (score 0):

After mapping the first three properties, I would see the duplication and replace it by iterating over the properties and assigning them using reflection. That only needs a few tests: 0 properties, 1 property, 5 properties, target object doesn't have the expected properties, source object doesn't have the expected properties. Now I can reuse this general mapping engine everywhere else in all my applications and I don't have to check it each time I use it.